# Where do args passed to systemd have to reside?

Tags: systemd

[Arguments](https://superuser.com/questions/728951/systemd-giving-my-service-multiple-arguments)  or [-flags](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077778/how-do-i-pass-flags-when-starting-a-systemd-service) can be passed to systemd `systemctl` when e.g. starting a service.

But do the args need to reside in

1. the service
2. systemd
3. somewhere else

In other words, must the args be callable to/by the service itself (as I assume)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments usually live in the service file in the `ExecStart=` line.

```
# /lib/systemd/system/myservice.service
[Unit]
ExecStart=/bin/myprogram arg1 arg2
```

---

One of the links you provided uses **templated** services to define one of the arguments

```
# /lib/systemd/system/myservice@.service
[Unit]
ExecStart=/bin/myprogram %i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That will let you enable multiple instance of the same service with different arguments.

```
systemctl enable --now myservice@arg1.service
systemctl enable --now myservice@arg2.service
```

That will cause two instances to run, with different arguments:  `/bin/myprogram arg1` and `/bin/myprogram/arg2`.

---

> is it possible to start a service without it opening a GUI?

Now you're getting specific.  It sounds like you have a service which launches a GUI that manages docker.  In that case I suspect `systemd` is the wrong place to look.  Your `docker-desktop.service` probably doesn't run any of your containers, but just provides an interface to interact with the service that does.  That service could manage all container instances as child processes without `systemd` involved.

Take a look (just guessing) at

```
systemctl list-units *docker*
```

I bet that will reveal the actual service that is responsible for managing your containers.

Docker containers don't usually require an executive like this, and it is often possible to manage them via systemd, but you need to have a `.service` file for each container, each with its own set of arguments.

Comment: Hi Stewart, thanks a lot for answering my question that I, unfortunately, may have phrased in a way not intended. My concern is perhaps the parameters more than the args. The matter is "what" takes the parameters when passing args to systemd. Systemd is responsible for starting docker; docker is responsible for making images and starting containers. I know it is possible to use docker without the desktop version, but I am playing with the desktop version; just not with the GUI, which I close all the time. I will rephrase title and text to get closer to my intend.

Comment: I removed the more specific part of the question. You may want to update your answer. I am still not sure it answered the general one though I suspect your answer is my option 1.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really understand what you mean.  It doesn't matter if you call them parameters, arguments, or flags.  Are you perhaps talking about forwarding args when calling `systemctl start` directly?  Like `systemctl start myservice.service -- arg1 arg2`?  Systemctl doesn't support that.